# why click event is not working in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

why click event is not working .I am using react js .here is my code
http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/dMEvzP

```
var  App= React.createClass({
  handleClick:function(){
 console.log('000');
    alert('--')
},
  render(){
    return <button onClick="{this.handleClick()}">hello</button>
  }

});
React.render(<App name='test'/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and Remove `"` and `()` from onClick, and try, below is the sample code,

```
var  App= React.createClass({
 handleClick:function(){
 console.log('000');
    alert('--')
},
  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>hello</button>
  }

});
React.render(<App name='test'/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "" and () from this.handleClick()

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `render` function put this

```
return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>hello</button>
```